# How to install SignalR library on .NET CORE versoin 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm having some troubles adding the Signal R library to my project. I was using the version 2.1 but now I want to use the version 3.1 and everytime I add signal R it gives me an error saying that it can't find the server. I've already tried following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio but it's not working. Can someone help me?

Comment: It's working. I'm using it. Post your code **and** full error messages or exceptions. `can't find the server` can simply mean the URL is wrong. Perhaps you use the wrong Javascript client. Perhaps the configuration code is wrong. We can't guess

Comment: I had a mistake on my code. I followed the tutorial once more and it worked just fine. Thank you anyway